# Python while loop with or not giving expeted output

Tags: python, while-loop, logic

This is my loop:

```
sure = input('Are you sure that you wish to reset the program?(y/n)')
while sure != 'y' or sure != 'n':
    sure = input('Please awnser y or n, Are you sure that you wish to reset the program?(y/n)')
```

The loop carries on looping even if `y` or `n` are entered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the condition to

```
while sure != 'y' and sure != 'n':
```

Your condition as written will *always* be `True` no matter what they enter. An alternative would be

```
while sure not in ('y','n'):
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the not in suggestion

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `and` instead of `or` . When doing `or` it will continue to the loop if sure is not `y` as well `n` , but sure cannot be both at the same time, hence it loops forever.

Example -

```
sure = input('Are you sure that you wish to reset the program?(y/n)')
while sure != 'y' and sure != 'n':
    sure = input('Please awnser y or n, Are you sure that you wish to reset the program?(y/n)')
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your logical expression:

```
sure != 'y' or sure != 'n'
```

Using De Morgan's Law, this could be rephrased as:

```
!(sure == 'y' and sure == 'n')
```

Obviously, `sure` can never be *both* `'y'` and `'n'`, so this doesn't work. What you want instead is:

```
sure != 'y' and sure != 'n'
```